# multitenant database with spring mvc, hibernate and Oauth2

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, multi-tenant

I am developing hybrid mobile application and have implemented java based rest api based on spring mvc and hibernate. I am Using MySql as database. For authentication i implemented Oauth2.0.

Currently i have a single client, so i used single data-source. but my requirement changed i have 5 clients each having min 1000 users.  so decided to use multi-tenancy separate database scheme. but there are some users for whom i need to fetch data from all tenants or in combination of tenants and after some calculation display their result in dashboard.

and i also want to implement an additional layer of separate tenant specific queue which hold tenant specific request.

How can i do this?

Comment: please post some line of code (java class, properties file, ...)

Comment: Is it only the database that is multi-tenant or is it also the Application, or will you have 5 instances of the application (possibly on the same web-container)?

Comment: they are different schools of same group so i decided to provide same application but keep data in separate database but higher management having access of all the dbs .

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like this before, using EclipseLink and supporting MySQL (and 6 other DBMS). In that case the application was used within an enterprise, but you could have multiple projects isolating different departments (tenants), and you could define users that could see data from all projects.

The key is to introduce a Tenant entity as the top level entity in your ER diagram, every other entity belongs to a tenant.

```
@Entity
public class Tenant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<User> users;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<TenantConfiguration> configurations;
}
```

One challenge you will have to deal with is security. On every request you have to verify if the user has permission to access the requested entities (never trust the front end). This means that you OAuth2 Authentication (created during login) needs to contain a reference to an entity which allows you to determine the users tenancy, and permissions. For performance reasons you typically include the Tenancy (TENANCY_ID) in JPA queries to avoid loading a lot of data and filtering it in memory.

Good Luck

Comment: to implement this i need to build an central database contains login information as well as auth token information?

Comment: Klaus Groenbaek: i implemented this but problem is when i implementing for management [having multiple role in multiple tenant], i have to fetch data according to their role from corresponding tenant and perform some operations.